# what is a more elegant way of returning True and False with this if/else statement in Python?

Tags: python

I keep getting an error saying 'Unnecessary "else" after "return"'

What is it trying to tell me, and what would be a more elegant way to code this logic?

```
for selected_node in NODES:
    if pm.nodeType(selected_node) == 'file':
        msg = 'correct type of nodes selected'
        LOGGER_TEXTURE_SWAP.debug(msg)
        return True
    else:
        msg = 'incorrect type of nodes selected'
        LOGGER_TEXTURE_SWAP.debug(msg)
        return False
```

Comment: You have a for loop that can only ever run one iteration. It returned during the first loop whether the condition is true or not. It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: What is giving you an error for the `else:`? I don't think this is an error, it is redundant as you don't need it. Just remove it and unindent the body. The loop is unnecessary as well.

Comment: Error is the wrong word to use. PyLint is throwing that warning, and I an trying to figure out how to better code that logic

Comment: This will only loop once... what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: i am looping through a list of nodes to check if their type is valid, and if not, return False.  removing the else and unindenting seems to have fixed the issue though.

Comment: Maybe they don't want to check if the array is empty before accessing the content (not a good coding practice, but I've seen this coding pattern).

Comment: By the way, it's fine using an `else` after a return... kind of a shame the PyLint gives a warning, unless it's to enforce a coding style.

Answer (score 1):

I try to recreate the logic of your snippet and I use the latest python 3.8.3

```
nodes = ['file', 'folder', 'directory']

for node in nodes:
    if node == 'file':
        print(node)
        return True
    else:
        print('something else')
        return False
```

and I get SyntaxError: 'return' outside function. Which is understandable since return should be an output of a function.

So, then I make it as a function, as follow.

```
nodes = ['file', 'folder', 'directory']

def myprogram():
    for node in nodes:
        if node == 'file':
            print(node)
            return True
        else:
            print('something else')
            return False
myprogram()
```

Now I got 'file' printed and 'True' output.
So, python works as expected.